# How to detect if XML element generated by JAXB is optional or required

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm working with some JAXB generated classes.

Is there a way to determine if an Element is optional or required via code? 
I have some elements that may or may not need to be required depending on input values.
E.g: some very quick clunky outline code to give you an idea on what I mean:

```
XMLElement xmlElement = ....;
InputValue inputValue = ....;

 if(xmlElement.isRequired && inputValue.isNull()) {
         //keep empty xmlElement
 } else if(xmlElement.isRequired && ! inputValue.isNull()) {
     xmlElement.setInputValueAttribute(inputValue.toString());
 } else if(!xmlElement.isRequired && inputValue.isNull()) {
     // don't use the empty xmlElement
 } else if(!xmlElement.isRequired && ! inputValue.isNull()) {
     xmlElement.setInputValueAttribute(inputValue.toString());
 }
```

Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: The schema is what determines whether or not it's required. You could conceivably instrument something within your code to produce appropriate errors if a field you deem as required is not present, but as far as figuring out if it's required via code, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the xsd is generating the java classes as necessary. The problem is just when I need to use them. I have different scenarios: sometimes the "inputValue" is empty but the tag is required, so therefore I should instantiate that element class for XML generation with "no content". Where another scenario is the inputValue is empty and the tag is optional, therefore I should not instantiate the class for XML generation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems we can't (or at least I couldn't figure it out! JAXB experts please feel free answer :)).

I actually realised since I already know which elements are mandatory and which are not (manually by the XSD), I basically just added a Helper method in the code which generates the XML class code. This Helper is called when creating optional tags, and just checks for null/empty inputValues, and adds the elements/attributes appropriately.

E.g.

```
createXMLElement(value, type, listOfElements);

private void createXMLElement(InputValue value, XMLElementType type, List<XMLElement> listOfElements) {

 XMLElement result = null;
 if (null != value && !value.isEmpty()) {
    result = new XMLElement();
    // populate the atts etc

    listOfElements.add(result);

 }

}
```

The problem with this is the manual interference, I would have preferred to have this automated. Meh, fine for a first version I guess. :)
Additionally, it is limited to single Element type (XMLElement in this example).